# ERROR Json-server: SyntaxError: Malformed JSON in file: db.json Unexpected token � in JSON at position

Tags: javascript, reactjs, json, json-server

I hope you are doing well. I have a problem while using the json-server package (^0.17.3). When I run the command "json-server --watch db.json", it throws the following error:

> hi!
>
> Loading db.json
> SyntaxError: Malformed JSON in file: db.json
> Unexpected token � in JSON at position 0
> at FileAsync.parse [as deserialize] ()
> at C:\Users\LUIS\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\json-server\node_modules\lowdb\adapters\FileAsync.js:41:35

I have tried reinstalling json-server, but the error persists, and I can't think of anything else. I'm providing my JSON file, which I have tested with JSON Lint and it shows as valid.

```
{    "Usuario": [
     {
       "idusuario": 1,
       "nombre_usuario": "Nombre Usuario 1",
       "clave": "Clave Usuario 1",
       "username": "Username Usuario 1"
     },
     {
       "idusuario": 2,
       "nombre_usuario": "Nombre Usuario 2",
       "clave": "Clave Usuario 2",
       "username": "Username Usuario 2"
     }    ],    "Lista_compras": [
     {
       "idlista": 1,
       "fecha_lista": "Fecha Lista 1",
       "nombre_lista": "Nombre Lista 1",
       "idusuario": 1
     },
     {
       "idlista": 2,
       "fecha_lista": "Fecha Lista 2",
       "nombre_lista": "Nombre Lista 2",
       "idusuario": 2
     }    ],    "lista_producto": [
     {
       "idlista": 1,
       "idproducto": 1,
       "estado": "Estado Producto 1"
     },
     {
       "idlista": 2,
       "idproducto": 2,
       "estado": "Estado Producto 2"
     }    ],    "Producto": [
     {
       "idproducto": 1,
       "nombre_producto": "Nombre Producto 1",
       "precio": "Precio Producto 1",
       "idproveedor": 1,
       "fecha_creacion": "Fecha Creacion Producto 1"
     },
     {
       "idproducto": 2,
       "nombre_producto": "Nombre Producto 2",
       "precio": "Precio Producto 2",
       "idproveedor": 2,
       "fecha_creacion": "Fecha Creacion Producto 2"
     }    ],    "Proveedor": [
     {
       "idproveedor": 1,
       "nombre_proveedor": "Nombre Proveedor 1",
       "fecha_creacion": "Fecha Creacion Proveedor 1"
     },
     {
       "idproveedor": 2,
       "nombre_proveedor": "Nombre Proveedor 2",
       "fecha_creacion": "Fecha Creacion Proveedor 2"
     }    ]  }
```

I will use it for a React application with Vite.js. I'm providing this information in case there might be any compatibility issues.

**[UPDATE]** the error is that I was creating the JSON file with Visual Studio code and the text format was adding invalid characters, I did it again in notepad saving it with UTF-8 encoding and it worked correctly c:

Comment: Open the JSON file in a hex editor and check if there are any weird invisible bytes at the start…

Comment: Do not add "SOLVED" to your title, nor in your question. If you found a solution, post it in the appropriate section below (i.e. the Answers section), or, as this question is closed, as a comment here. Or, you can also simply delete this question altogether.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

File is correct and the problem is not with JSON Server package. I created brand new project, installed json-server@0.17.3, created file "db.json" with the content you provided and got no error. Here are some things to try:

- Check whether path to db.json is correct.
- Run your terminal using administrator rights (or sudo)
- If that won't help, create new project, install only json-server and then try to access your db.json.

Comment: Hi, how are you doing? I created a new project with vite and react and installed only json-server, I ran it with administrator permissions but the error persists :(
According to what you tell me, what would be the correct directory to host the JSON file?

Comment: I solved it, the error is that I was creating the file with Visual Studio code and the text formatting was adding invalid characters, I did it again in notepad and it worked correctly c: